# MediaPlayer destroyed when set new setContentView

Tags: java, android, layout, android-mediaplayer

When I click on a button,it will change the `layout` of my page from Layout A to Layout B. My problem is I want to keep my `MediaPlayer` alive but changing `layout` destroys it.

How do I prevent this from happening?

I have tried

> onSavedInstanceState (but this method doesn't save MediaPlayer state or atleast in my knowledge)
>
> SharedPreferences (same result as above)

My button code is a simple one

```
    view1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);
      }
    });

    view2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
      }
    });
```

**EDIT**

I am playing from a live stream, so using `mp.seekTo(int)` is not desirable

**EDIT 2**

After testing all the answers given to me, inflating the layout does keep it alive but it was not how I expected.

The thing is, I wanted to change Layout A which has 1 `SurfaceView` to Layout B which has 2 `SurfaceView`. Inflating the layout would keep the `MediaPlayer` alive but the surface does not follow the layout correctly

Comment: Simply use `LayoutInflater` instead of `setContentView`

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use the service for playing music using Media Player.

2.You change the layout, using LayoutInflator instead of "setContentView" and Second layout should be part of first one is better. so your buttons for changing the layout, should be first layout.

3.use the following code It should work.

```
  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_layout,relativeLayout);
    }
});
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_layout2,relativeLayout);
    }
});
```

4. where relativeLayout is part of the First Layout so you just inflate the another layout using this one.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
       playIntent=new Intent(NewLayoutActivity.this,MusicService.class);
       //playIntent.putExtra(MusicService.URL,"http://charan.com/tcs/audio/Chandana_Charchita.mp3");
       playIntent.setAction(MusicService.MAIN_ACTION);
       startService(playIntent);
       bindService(playIntent,musicServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
       Log.i(TAG,"onStart Called");
       super.onStart();
   }

   public ServiceConnection musicServiceConnection=new ServiceConnection() {

       @Override
       public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinderObject) {
           myBinder= (MusicService.MyBinder) iBinderObject;

           musicService=myBinder.getService();
           mConnection=true;
           musicService.initializeMediaPlayer("http://charan.com/tcs/audio/Chandana_Charchita.mp3");
           Log.i(TAG,"Service Bounded...");

       }

       @Override
       public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
           mConnection=false;

       }
   };

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
       if(mConnection){
           unbindService(musicServiceConnection);
           mConnection=false;
       }
       super.onDestroy();
   }
   ```
5. Service Code... when your service bounded, then initialize media player in the service.

   ```
    public void initializeMediaPlayer(String url){

        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
       player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
       player.setOnErrorListener(this);
       player.setOnCompletionListener(this);

      if(TextUtils.isEmpty(url)){
          url=defaultUrl;
      }
      try {
          player.setDataSource(url);
         // player.prepareAsync();
          player.prepare();
          player.start();
          player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
     // mState="preparing";
       mState="playing";

   }
   ```
6. So your service won't disturb here. even if you change the layout.

Comment: @Suresh It's very bad idea to run a service just to keep single instance alive

Answer (score 0):

You can use Singleton class to initialize any object just for once and using instance you can do anything you want.

it won't destroy until you do it by self or application get destroyed.

i think it will resolve your purpose for sure.

Happy coding!